# Docker Compose understanding the ports mapping

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Docker newbie here. I am trying to understand the meaning of the following:

```
services:
  mongo1:
   hostname: mongo1
   container_name: mongo1
   image: mongo:5.0.6
   expose:
      - 27017
   ports:
     - 27011:27017
   restart: always
```

Note the ports: **27011:27017**. When the Docker is up and running, I can access the MongoDB server via port 27011, so what is the 27017? And why do I need to expose it like the following?

```
expose:
  - 27017
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`expose:` is a legacy implementation detail of first-generation Docker networking.  It does almost nothing in current Docker, and it's always safe to remove it from Compose files.  No other changes are required.

`ports:` describes how to map a port from the host system to a port in the container.  The second port number is a fixed property of the image and is typically the "normal" port the container listens on; in your example MongoDB normally listens on port 27017 and the second port number must be exactly that.  The first port number can be any otherwise-unused port on the host system.

Comment: Thank you David Maze; who about the port? 27017 how would you read it in plain english: 27011:27017 what's the 27017? thank you!

Comment: I've expanded the answer a little: "map port 27011 on the host to port 27017 in the container, where 27017 is the normal MongoDB port."

Comment: `27017` (used in the `expose` option) is the container port that you would like to expose to a linked service (like another docker container on the same network you define). The `expose` option will not expose the port to the host machine. [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)

Comment: "Linked service" is also a legacy implementation detail of first-generation Docker networking, and it's also almost always safe to delete `links:`.